# Documenting keyboard macros Can I have a doc string for fset the same way as defun

Tags: keyboard-macros, doc-strings

I often create and save elaborate keyboard macros that I wish to use later, and hope to be prompted for the proper context to use them.  I note that if I manually write a function to use as a command I can have a doc string

```
(defun my-handy-command ()
  "Some helpful guidance on when to use this"
```

However keyboard macros get saved as

```
(fset `my-named-kbd-macro
  (kmacro-lambda-form
```

can I supply a docstring somehow.  If I can't apply a docstring to `fset` what is the quickest and easiest way to go from a recorded keyboard macro to a usable emacs command with a docstring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `defalias` instead of `fset`. You use it like `fset` but it takes a docstring as third argument.

eg:

```lisp
(defalias 'pastebelow
  (kmacro-lambda-form [?y ?y ?p] 0 "%d")
  "This is my keyboard macro.")
```

for Emacs version < 29

or

```lisp
(defalias 'pastebelow
  (kmacro "y y p")
  "This is my keyboard macro.")
```

for Emacs version >= 29.

(`y y p` because I am an evil user).

Of course you can use `M-x insert-kbd-macro` after saving it with `kmacro-name-last-macro` (`C-x C-k n`).

Comment: `defalias` worked as advertised and I am using it now.  I am however hesitant to accept your answer because I cannot reproduce your example.  When I evaluate it I get an error on the line `(kmacro "y y p")` 

Debugger entered--Lisp error: (void-function kmacro)
  (kmacro "y y p")
  ...

If you can clarify why that doesn't work for my version, or what I'm doing wrong or fix up your example, I will accept your answer.

Comment: Ah, I see. I am using Emacs 29, I did not know this worked differently in Emacs < 29. I have updated the answer. Thanks!